# Verifying integration formulas for continuous functions

Tags: integration, derivatives

In some exercises the task was to verify some integration formulas of continuous integrands. For example (Tom Apostol Calculus, section 5.11, exercise 28):

$$
\int{\frac{\sqrt{ax+b}}{x}}dx = 2\sqrt{a+bx} + a\int{\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{a+bx}}} + C
$$

Instead of computing the integral itself, is there any problem with simply using the primitives (e.g. in Leibniz notation), because all integrands are continuous, and any indefinite integral of a continuous function $f$ is also a primitive of $f$ ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4194378/clarification-about-indefinite-integral-being-a-primitive))?

In other words, let:

$$
P(x) = \int{\frac{\sqrt{ax+b}}{x}}dx \\
A(x) = 2\sqrt{a+bx} \\
B(x) = a\int{\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{a+bx}}} \\
$$

Because all integrands are continuous, is following a valid proof of the first equation? $$
1. A'(x) + B'(x) - P'(x) = 0  \implies  \\
2. A(x) + B(x) - P(x) = -C \implies \\
3. P(x) = A(x) + B(x) + C \implies \\
4. \int{\frac{\sqrt{ax+b}}{x}}dx = 2\sqrt{a+bx} + a\int{\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{a+bx}}} + C
$$

#1 can easily be computed to be true. $A'(x)$ is simple power function, and $P'(x)$ and $B'(x)/a$ are just the integrands, because they are continuos. 
#2 is true from the Theorem 5.2 (where $Q(x) = A(x) + B(x) - P(x)$ is the constant function).

I'm looking forward to someone pointing out what I'm missing (if I am missing something).

Thanks!

Comment: That is correct. Even when you come up with a formula yourself, it is a common way of checking that you haven't made a mistake.

Comment: Why not make that an answer to the question, if you are certain it is correct?

Comment: Because "Yes that is correct" doesn't make for a good answer. Solution validation questions tend to only get answers beyond a "yes" comment when the solution doesn't validate and we have to explain why. Yours does validate, and I see little to add to it. The fact that you paid attention to the continuity requirement of the fundamental theorem of calculus means that you've been even more thorough than most students at this level (well done, by the way).

Comment: Thank you, Paul! If I say I am correct, than I agree with you it's not very useful. However, if an expert says "Yes, that is correct" to my question, then I think it is a good answer to my question, especially when we think about potential future readers of the post (e.g. like this it looks not answered). With that said, I will let you decide, but I do not intend to answer my own question.